# how to get content from a Div that has a span which also has some content?

Tags: javascript

How to get content from a Div that has a span which also has some content?

```
<div id="test">
 this is a DIV
 <span>
  This is a span
 </span>
</div>

alert(document.getElementById('test').innerText);
```

The code alerts me with This is a DIV This is a span.Im looking to get the content only from the DIV.

Comment: could you just not give the span an ID?

Comment: @thescientist: yes... but how would that help?

Comment: because then you can just get the inner HTML of the span instead....   alert(document.getElementById('my_span').innerText);

Comment: @thescientist: _"Im looking to get the content only from the DIV."_

Comment: where does it say only?  he just says a span inside a div.  it was not made clear that he had no access to the markup.

Comment: @thescientist: Sorry, I don't follow. The OP wants to return the text _"this is a DIV"_ - how would adding an ID to the `span` help to do that?

Comment: doh.  my bad.  sorry, not that I was disagreeing with your solution.  Just didn't get the entire gist of the OP's question.

Comment: @thescientist: No problem - I thought I was missing something! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`nodeValue`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue):

```
document.getElementById('test').childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

**[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/5L3rd/)**

Comment: @Town thanks for the answer,it worked!! will mark it as the answer when it lets me,says i have to wait for a couple of mins

Comment: What would you need to do if there was more data after the span?  would he also need to reference chilnodes[1] and so on?

Comment: @Limey: `childNodes[1]` is the `<span>`. If there was just text afterwards, `childNodes[2]` would be the text.  Give it a go in the demo.

Comment: This solution only works if you know the index of the textnode. For a more robust solution, see my response below.

Comment: @Town nodeValue is not fully supported in old browsers. http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue

Comment: @hungryMind: which _old browsers_ are you talking about in particular? IE5.5? Safari 1.3? Take a look at [jQuery browser compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility) too - I think you'll find `nodeValue` is better supported.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will return all of the text in the target div, no matter where it is or how many elements are within the div.

You can do this by iterating through the target element's children and asking which ones are TEXT_NODEs.

```
nodes = document.getElementById('test').childNodes;
text = "";
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
   if(nodes[i].nodeType==document.TEXT_NODE) {
       text += nodes[i].nodeValue;
   }
}
alert(text);
```

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uAmt6/)

Comment: +1 hughes, that's a good solution if the OP's requirements are more complex than the question suggests.

Comment: Thank  you for the answer,im sorry m8 i hav already marked Town's response as the answer.Yours is more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

This technically works:

```
var html = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
alert(html.substr(0, html.indexOf('<span>')));
```

Answer (score -2):

use jquery

**UPDATED**

$("#test>span").parent().contents(':not(span)').text()

Comment: @hungryMind just out of curiosity,if the DIV had multiple spans and other DIVs the above code wont work,will it?Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Why not, jquery will pick all the span which are immediate children of #test, and then go back to parent, it will skip all the spans inside (probably u need to use not('>span') ) and get the text of div only. I have not tested it, but it should work.

Comment: `(1)` jQuery isn't in the tags for the question `(2)` jQuery's not required to do this `(3)` including any library purely to do something this simple is overkill `(4)` Your code doesn't work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/962SS/).

Comment: @Tom, 1. jquery is not in the tag, but thats an option 2. User is not writing only this code, using lib may help him in other functionality 3. Not always, jquery is well tested and cross browser code which helps user write code quickly 4. Updated code works.